# dotnet restore in docker container says NU1301: Unable to load the service index for source

Tags: .net, docker, nuget

even after giving feed and pat values with wget command docker container still says NU1301: Unable to load the service index for source, here is the docker file

```
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/aspnet:6.0.2-bullseye-slim AS base
WORKDIR /app
EXPOSE 80
EXPOSE 443
FROM ubuntu:latest
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/sdk:6.0-bullseye-slim AS build
WORKDIR /src
COPY src/ /src/

COPY /nuget.config ./


ENV FEED_URL="value"
ENV PAT=value

RUN wget -qO- https://aka.ms/install-artifacts-credprovider.sh | bash
ENV DOTNET_SYSTEM_NET_HTTP_USESOCKETSHTTPHANDLER=0
ENV NUGET_CREDENTIALPROVIDER_SESSIONTOKENCACHE_ENABLED true
ENV VSS_NUGET_EXTERNAL_FEED_ENDPOINTS {\"endpointCredentials\": [{\"endpoint\":\"${FEED_URL}\", \"username\":\"name\", \"password\":\"${PAT}\"}]}

RUN dotnet restore "/src/API.csproj" -s ${FEED_URL} -s https://api.nuget.org/v3/index.json

RUN dotnet restore "/src/API.csproj"
```

Comment: Try `dotnet add package DoesNotExist` to see if a more detailed error message is reported. It might not be an HTTP 401, although if it is, it suggests that the credentials are not being supplied correctly.  Also, is `${FEED_URL}` an Azure DevOps feed?

Comment: @zivkan I created a new PAT value and tried it, it worked. But, sometimes it gives the same error